# Alternative to x-forwarding, or how to speed up x-forwarding

Tags: ssh, remote-desktop, remote-access, remoting

I do my development on VM's, and pass windows back to my Host via X-forwarding with the following command:

`ssh -Yc aes256-gcm@openssh.com me@local-vm-ip`

This works fine except that it tends to be slow; I have specified to use a faster encryption method, which makes it workable, except when connecting to the vm from another workstation on the network (when ssh'ing to guest from host, is serviceable).

I'm looking to offload my hypervisor duties to a server rather than my desktop, so figuring out how to better access my vm's over a network has become a priority.

What alternatives are there? I'm looking for:

- Keeping the aspect of just forwarding application windows to the connecting client. This integrates seamlessly with the host's resources (clipboard, multi monitors, etc). Another form of keeping things well integrated would be acceptable.
- fast

I am running modern Linux environments, will be using Ubuntu 20/22, along with Fedora 36+

Workarounds tried (and failed):

- Even faster ssh encryption/no encryption; what I specified above from previous reading seems to be the fastest currently available w/o having to rebuild ssh binaries (which I don't want to have to do)
- X2Go; Seemed slick, but doesn't work with modern GNOME (Not that I have a particular affinity, but it is default and don't feel like futzing with changing desktop environments for all VM's). Also unsure on client host integration, but could be that I just couldn't get that far.

Comment: The problem is not encryption. The cause is that X is very talkative and it degrades awfully if the link has high latency, which is typical for Internet. I think x2go or its origin/predecessor, nx, is the only viable solution. You really should explore this more; get rid of Gnome if it stays on the way; get rid of Wayland which seemed a good idea but it couldn't emerge even after ten years of development and only complicates things.